# SQL query get newly duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have this table structure

```
User
====
*Id
*Email
*City
*DateCreated
```

with this data:

```
Id Email                           City         DateCreated
1  eleven@gmail.com                Hawkins      01-01-2018
2  jim.hopper@gmail.com            Hawkins      01-01-2018
3  mike.wheeler@gmail.com          Hawkins      01-01-2018
4  dustin.henderson@gmail.com      Hawkins      01-01-2018
5  eleven@gmail.com                Hawkins      01-01-2021
6  eleven@gmail.com                Pittsburgh   01-01-2021
```

I want to run a query which returns only the latest duplicate record (same email and city):

```
5  eleven@gmail.com                Hawkins      01-01-2021
```

Comment: duplicate according to what? email and/or city and/or date or?

Comment: @jarlh email and city. Just updated question accordingly.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: microsoft sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use window functions to get this result**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Email, t.City ORDER BY t.DateCreated DESC) rn,
        COUNT(*)     OVER (PARTITION BY t.Email, t.City) cnt
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE t.cnt > 1 AND t.rn = 1
```

Remove the `COUNT` and its filter if you want also rows which have no duplicates at all.

Comment: thanks but there seems to be an incorrect syntax issue that won't let me try this.

Comment: Sorry missing comma and FROM

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `window functions`.

```
;WITH FilteredResult AS (
    SELECT 
        Id,
        Email,
        City,
        DateCreated,
        DuplicatedRows  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Email, City ORDER BY Id)
    FROM your_table_name
)
SELECT *
FROM FilteredResult
WHERE DuplicatedRows = 1
```

Comment: thanks but there seems to be an incorrect syntax issue that won't let me try this

Comment: Now fixed it. It was missing the `AS` keyword after the `FilteredResult`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the record shown is not a duplicate because the city differs from ID 5 and ID 6.

But you could probably do row_number function and partition by email and date created.

Here's a good example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/rownumber-function-with-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server1

Comment: thanks but I'm talking about records 1 and 5, in which email is the same and city is the same, but DateCreated is different.

Comment: Then row_number will work perfectly, you can partition by date desc and the top most result will be your duplicate

Comment: sorry this leaves me in the same spot as I'm not familiar with row_number. Could you please elaborate?